# Is there a simple way to use AWS Cognito for user authentication?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to build my first AWS web app with Elastic Beanstalk. The idea of the app is that it's essentially inventory management, using DynamoDB to store inventory data. The backend for the site is being done in Java.

I'm looking for a relatively easy to use user authentication system, as I don't really want to spend all the time coding a complete system on my own. Just need an easy way for users to log in, with different groups of users having different permissions. Don't even need a registration system as for this project accounts will be created for clients with the login info given directly to them.

I've been looking at AWS Cognito, but the more I try to learn about it the more I just get confused. It seems that while the Java API for Cognito helps eliminate some of the work, it still requires quite a bit of configuration to get a basic user auth system working. Other options I've looked at include a 3rd party provider, such as [StormPath](https://stormpath.com/), as it seems like this would be an easier system, though it comes with a disadvantage as it means the whole app isn't localized to my AWS account. I've also looked at [LambdAuth](https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth) but it looks slightly dated.

Is there a simple way to make a user authentication system with Cognito that won't take a ton of time, or would I be better of going with a 3rd party?

Comment: It is a difficult question. I think Cognito User Pools are easy to work with. And if you dont event need signup and email/phone verification it is two calls in the SDK. Authenticate where you provide username and password (that the user enters in the app). This will give you a session containing tokens. The you use these tokens to authenticate with aws. The SDK will even take care of token refresh. You can use the tokens manually or use Federated Identity to map these tokens to an IAM user that can in your case access DynamoDB.